# No suitable method found for inflate(int), tryingto use findViewbyID outside of activity

Tags: java, android, textview, layout-inflater

Title basically says the issue. I referred to this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481 to solve the latter issue but then its giving me the former issue.

```
public class PbfSampleApplication extends Application {
public static final String TAG = "PbfSampleApplication";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    startService(new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), 
PbfSampleService.class));

    FlicManager.init(this.getApplicationContext(), "2125f7c3-0d0e-42d5-88fe-
fda8765867d6", "94d6448c-22d3-4d2e-951f-f625f60f471a");

    FlicManager manager = FlicManager.getManager();

    for (FlicButton button : manager.getKnownButtons()) {
        button.connect();
        listenToButtonWithToast(button);
    }
}


public void listenToButtonWithToast(FlicButton button) {
    button.addEventListener(new FlicButtonAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonUpOrDown(FlicButton button, boolean wasQueued, int timeDiff, boolean isUp, boolean isDown) {
            if (isDown) {


                View v =LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main);
                 //Above line has the error
                View innerView = v.findViewById(R.id.number);           

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button " + button + " was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:017702329065"));
                startActivity(callIntent);


            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

I know I'm supposed to pass in an int but when I check the method in the developer website it appears the argument is correctly formatted, so I'm not sure what else I need to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of LayoutInflater before calling it:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
View innerView = v.findViewById(R.id.number);
```

The second parameter is a `ViewGroup` that may be null. The `LayoutInflater` does not have an inflate method that takes only one argument

Comment: That eliminated the error in the indicated line, but I'm getting an error with the getContext() when I'm creating the instance of layout inflater. What do I do with it? This is all very new to me and its my first android app so apologies in advance

Comment: Use PbfSampleApplication.this instead of getContext() and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah now its fine but Im running into a separate issue now. Im trying to take this EditText number input, parse it as a phone number, and then call it on that method call. Im parsing it like
`LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(PbfSampleApplication.this);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
EditText innerView = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.number);
String actualnum="tel:"+innerView.getText().toString().trim();
`